# Path mapping using `paths` not work properly?

Tags: typescript

with the following config in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@foobar/*": ["packages/*/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

The project layout looks like:

- projectRoot

  - tsconfig.json
  - packages

    - dir1
    - dir2
    - shared

      - src

        - dom

          - utils.ts
        - index.ts

This works fine.

```
import { baz } from '@foobar/shared'; // mapped to `packages/shared/src/index.ts`
```

I expect this will work, but it won't

```
import { baz } from '@foobar/shared/dom/utils';
```

But this will work, which was weird because I have already included the `src` in the `paths`.

```
import { hasClosestElement } from '@muku-ui/shared/src/dom/utils';
```

Is this a bug or I have missed something?

Answer (score 0):

This one `'@foobar/shared/dom/utils'` will never work, since you are explicitly looking for a directory named `dom` under directory `shared`. Based on the project layout you provided, there is not such directory under `shared`, it exists under `src` directory: `@foobar/shared/src/dom/utils`.